# Ctrl-T compiles, but no longer resumes/cancels on error (TeXworks version 0.6.7 / MiKTeX 22.8.28)

Tags: miktex, texworks, keyboard

(I'm using MiKTeX, but the issue is in the TeXworks user interface.)

Simply put, **Ctrl-T** builds the document, and until recently it would also *cancel* the build if you hit it when an error occurred. This was very fast and convenient, since Ctrl-T was like a start/stop, allowing you to fix the code, Ctrl-T again and build. It also didn't seem to care where the input focus was, which was helpful.

Since the last MiKTeX update (MiKTeX 22.8.28 / TeXworks 0.6.7) this no longer works; if an error occurs, you now have to manually cancel the build by typing in the console. Eventually I may get used to this, but it'll never be as quick.

Is there a way to configure it to behave as before? Does anyone know if this is a MiKTeX issue, or a regression in TeXworks?

I've not managed to find any discussions about this, which surprises me unless it's something odd that only affects my system.

(System is Ubuntu 20.04.5 LTS / Xfce 4.14.2)

Comment: well on windows ctrl+T interrupts, but it kills the process and so you get an unfinished log and broken aux-files so I wouldn't recommend that. Why don't you type x (on the keyboard, not by clicking on the console!) at an error so that tex can finish its business in a clean way?

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Thank you for the comment. That is what I do currently. The beauty of Ctrl-T is that it is reachable completely from the left hand, which is much faster. 'x' and Enter is either a long hand movement, or requires two-hand typing, and my right hand is usually on the mouse. But... I've just thought of a better alternative to all of this, which I will post as an answer - which is simply to use -halt-on-error. Thank you for the comment; not sure I would have thought of it had I not starting replying here!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution shortly after posting the question; it's not *quite* an exact answer to the question as asked, but is arguably a better solution.

**Use either the `-halt-on-error` or `-interaction=nonstopmode` switch when invoking pdftex.**

The former makes the compilation give up on the first error, which is what I personally prefer, since subsequent errors are often spurious if the first error relates to parsing.

The latter should suppress any attempts at interaction, and spit out all errors in one unbroken stream of output. I haven't tested this, although I will come back and add any relevant information if I find `-halt-on-error` to be inadequate.

Additionally, using either of these switches should leave the system in a well-defined state, which isn't the case with the old Ctrl-T build interruption.

Switches can be set by going into

`Edit` -> `Preferences` -> `Typesetting` -> `Processing tools`

where you can customise the arguments used to invoke TeX/LaTeX.